# String loops in jsp

Tags: jsp

How do I print out a string loop in a jsp file? I only want to print out Hello 10 times in a jsp file. So far I only have

```
   <%
   String[] hello = {"Hello"};
   for (int i = 10; i < hello.length; i++) {
      out.print("<P>" + hello[i] + "</p>");
   }
%>
```

from online googling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  It accomplishes your stated objective of "I only want to print out Hello 10 times in a jsp file."

```
  <%
   String hello = "Hello";
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      out.print("<P>" + hello + "</p>");
   }
   %>
```